# permutations with unique values adding array

Tags: python, php, r

I have an array with the following values:

```
result = [2000, 3000, 0, 1000, 1500, 5000]
```

And I also have the following possibilities

```
option1 = [1000, 1500, 0, 500, 750, 2500]

option2 = [500, 3000, 0, 200, 300, 1500]

option3 = [700, 50, 0, 200, 400, 600]

.

.

optionn = [700, 50, 0, 200, 400, 600]
```

I need to create a combination of the options that the sum of the values ​​1 of the options is equal to or greater than the value 1 of the result, and so with each of the positions of the arrays.

For example a solution for the problem is: option1 + option2 + option3 beause it sum result.

It would be something like this but instead of being a single number they are several numbers: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/all-unique-combinations-whose-sum-equals-to-k/

With what programming language could you do it? Do you know any examples?

Comment: Why option1 + option2 + option3 is a solution? The last position : 2500 + 1500 + 600 = 4600 < 5000.

Comment: It is a error. option1 + option2 + option3 is not a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a linear programming problem, which might have an efficient solution. But as I don't know about it, I am throwing a brute-force approach using python:

```py
import itertools
result = [2000, 3000, 0, 1000, 1500, 5000]
options = [[1000, 1500, 0, 500, 750, 2500],
           [500, 3000, 0, 200, 300, 1500],
           [700, 50, 0, 200, 400, 600],
           [700, 50, 0, 200, 400, 600]]

for r in range(1, len(options) + 1):
    for comb in itertools.combinations(options, r):
        if all(sum(y) >= x for x, *y in zip(result, *comb)):
            print(comb)
```

Output:

```
([1000, 1500, 0, 500, 750, 2500], [500, 3000, 0, 200, 300, 1500], [700, 50, 0, 200, 400, 600], [700, 50, 0, 200, 400, 600])
```

To remove obviously unnecessary calculations, you can loop over `r` *backwards*, and break the outer loop once no combinations satisfying the constraing are found in the inner loop.

Comment: This one works. Anyone know a way to optimize it even more? Thanks